# Can I use an f string to design a url for my discord.py bot's embeds' images?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm creating a command for a discord bot and I want it to be able to send me an animated sprite from the Pokemon Showdown website.

```py
@client.command()
async def dex(ctx, args):
  args_l = args.lower()
  if "," in args_l:
    args_split = args_l.split()
    pokemon = args_split[1]

    url = "https://media2.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/200.gif"
    tag = args_split[0]

    if tag == "shiny":
      url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani-shiny/{pokemon}.gif"
    elif tag == "mega":
      url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}-mega.gif"
  else:
    url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}.gif"
  
  embed = discord.Embed(title="POKEDEX", color=c, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
  embed.set_footer(text="Pokedex")
  embed.description = f"Pokemon: {pokemon}\n\nApplicable Tags: {tag}\n\nThis auction has increments of {increment}\n\nAutobuy: {ab}"
  embed.set_image(url=url)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I run this command, dex, my bot does not send an embed (`await ctx.send(embed=embed)` isn't sending an embed). There is no error message. When I try using a command that isn't added to the bot, it responds with a message, "I do not have this command" (which I set it to do with a `CommandNotFound` error checker).
I think the problem is either in the urls or the `embed.set_image(url=url)`.

Comment: Hey dogluva, please [edit] your post to include any debugging details for your code. Which parts actually run? Where does it stop? Editing it down to a [mcve] will help with this.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, this will help others better understand your problem and help you more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send pokemon, tag, ab, and increment variables even though they are not set when there is no ',' in args, also the urls have to have 'https://' at the front for it to work. Something like this seems to work but then again you need to make sure you cover the case where there is no ',' in `args`.

```
@client.command()
async def dex(ctx, args):
    pokemon = args
    args_l = args.lower()
    if "," in args_l:
        args_split = args_l.split(',')
        pokemon = args_split[1]

        url = "media2.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/200.gif"
        tag = args_split[0]

        if tag == "shiny":
            url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani-shiny/{pokemon}.gif"
        elif tag == "mega":
            url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}-mega.gif"
    else:
        url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}.gif"
    
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="POKEDEX", color=discord.Colour.random(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    embed.set_footer(text="Pokedex")
    embed.description = f"Pokemon: {pokemon}\n\nApplicable Tags: {tag}\n\nThis auction has increments of \n\nAutobuy: "
    embed.set_image(url="https://"+url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: like this]

Comment: Thanks, a really obvious mistake I should have been able to figure out from reading the documentation and my code, sorry for your time :/

Answer (score -1):

Without an error message, it is difficult to know for sure, but it looks like this is your problem:

If there is no `,` in your command, the `pokemon` variable is unset when you try to use it in `url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}.gif"`

It looks like you need to modify the `else` block to something like the following:

```
else:
    pokemon = args_l
    url = f"play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/{pokemon}.gif"
```

You also need to specify what character you're splitting with earlier on in the function, as `str.split()` without any argument splits on whitespace rather than a comma which appears to be what you want:

```
args_split = args_l.split(",")
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Might be a problem with the URL's, but other than that I don't really have any idea. Not sure because when I copy the url over and replace {pokemon} with any random pokemon's name, it works. I don't think it's a problem with discord embeds not supporting fstrings or gifs